# How to Clear entire Shape Layer in Microsoft VirtualEarth 6.3 using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps, shapes, virtual-earth

The code snippet shown below (HTML5/javascript) loads Microsoft **Bing Map** (**VirtualEarth 6.3**), then adds two Shape layers and two sample Pushpins, one per each layer.

**QUESTION**: What pure javascript function (or solution) to use in order to clear all pushpins from just the 1st layer keeping the other layer intact?
*Note: clear layer function should be implemented without deleting the entire layer.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Bing VE Map w/layers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // VE map
        var _map;
        // 1st shape layer
        var _layer1 ;
        // 2nd shape layer
        var _layer2;

        function MapLoad() {

            // load map
            _map = new VEMap('Map');
            _map.LoadMap();

            // center point (Columbus Circle NY)
            var _center = new VELatLong(40.7681, -73.9819);

            // set center point and initial zoom level
            _map.SetCenterAndZoom(_center, 12);

            // set Map style
            _map.SetMapStyle(VEMapStyle.Shaded);

            // add 1st shape layer1 to Map obj
            _layer1 = new VEShapeLayer()
            _map.AddShapeLayer(_layer1);

            // add 2nd shape layer2 to Map obj
            _layer2 = new VEShapeLayer()
            _map.AddShapeLayer(_layer2);

            // add pushpin to layer1
            var _pushpin1 = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, _center);
             _layer1.AddShape(_pushpin1);

            // add pushpin (Apple Store on 5th) to layer2
             var _pushpin2 = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, new VELatLong(40.7639, -73.9725));
             _layer2.AddShape(_pushpin2);


            // QUESTION: HOW TO CLEAR ALL SHAPES FROM LAYER 1, (BUT NOT DELETING THE ENTIRE LAYER)?
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="MapLoad();">
    <div id="Map" style="position:absolute; top:100px; height:90%; width:100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the dedicated method `DeleteAllShapes()` of the `VEShapeLayer` class, see the MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412473.aspx

See the example:

```
// Delete all shapes within the layer at the selected index.
function DeleteAllShapes()
{
  layer = map.GetShapeLayerByIndex(selIndex);
  layer.DeleteAllShapes();
  IndexChanged(selIndex);
}
```

Also, I would recommend to use AJAX v7.0 instead of v6.3 since it's now deprecated and due to be out of support on November 30, 2016.

Comment: Many thanks, @NicolasBoonaert! I have tested it and it works like a charm. Answer accepted, best regards,